# How to Insert data to database using automatic if statement?

Tags: c#, database, uwp

I have some data containing the words 1951-2015 and I want to enter into the database with functions if the data is located containing the word 1951 then folder_id = 1, if 1952 then folder_id = 2, if 1953 then folder_id = 3, etc.

Code:

```
if (nama == "1951")
{
    string K2013GUpdate = @"INSERT INTO undangundnag (folder_id,identifier,filename) SELECT 1 + namaFile ,'" + file1.FName +
    "' WHERE not exists (select folder_id AND identifier AND filename FROM undangundnag WHERE folder_id=1 and identifier='" + namaFile 
     AND filename='" + file1.FName)";
    K2013GQuery.Step();
}
else if (nama == "1952")
{
    string K2013GUpdate = @"INSERT INTO undangundnag (folder_id,identifier,filename) SELECT 2 + namaFile ,'" + file1.FName +
    "' WHERE not exists (select folder_id AND identifier AND filename FROM undangundnag WHERE folder_id=2 and identifier='" + namaFile 
     AND filename='" + file1.FName)";
    K2013GQuery.Step();
}
else if (nama == "1953")
{
    string K2013GUpdate = @"INSERT INTO undangundnag (folder_id,identifier,filename) SELECT 3 + namaFile ,'" + file1.FName +
    "' WHERE not exists (select folder_id AND identifier AND filename FROM undangundnag WHERE folder_id=3 and identifier='" + namaFile 
     AND filename='" + file1.FName)";
    K2013GQuery.Step();
}
```

How do I automatically enter data into the database with if statement without using if one by one?

Comment: [Woo SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)!

Comment: Seems like `int.Parse(nama) - 1950` would get you the value and you don't need to duplicate all that code.  Better yet rewrite your queries to use SQL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data residing in a fixed range from 1952 to 2015 then you can loop within the range instead of using if statement as below:

```
int folder_id=0;
for(int i=1951;i<=2015;i++){
  folder_id++;
 // if you want to execute your query for all the values in the range then you can omit this 'if' statement and write query inside loop.
  if(nama==i){
 // write your query here with the folder_id
    break;
   }
}
```

And if you want to pass a specific data between 1952-2015 and want to generate folder_id according to your requirement then you can do as given below:

```
void getFolderID(nama){ //nama could be 1951 or 1955 or 1961....
int j=1950; // to get folder_id from 1951-2015
int folder_id=nama-j;
// write your query as desired below
}
```